# Check for empty value in C# - Webmatrix

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I am populating an input field value where sometimes the value exists and sometimes it doesn't I need to check if the value is empty and show nothing if it is not. My current code is using .IsNullOrEmpty :

```
<input id="lead-entry" class="form-textbox" type="text" size="5" name="q15_2013Collections[0][]" 
 value="@(queryinputvalue.FirstOrDefault(r => r.field_name.Equals("q15_2013Collections[0][]")).field_data.IsNullOrEmpty 
       ? "" 
       : queryinputvalue.FirstOrDefault(r =>  r.field_name.Equals("q15_2013Collections[0][]")).field_data) " />
```

Which gives me the error:

```
Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
```

Thanks

Edit: this is the code I finally used:

**Helpers.cshtml**

```
@helper checkEmpty(IEnumerable<dynamic> queryinputvalue, string field_id) {    
    var reqValue = queryinputvalue.FirstOrDefault(r => r.field_name.Equals(field_id));
    var return_value = "";
    if(reqValue != null){
        return_value = reqValue.field_data;
    } else {
        return_value = "";
        }
    @return_value
}
```

**On Page**

```
@{
IEnumerable<dynamic> queryinputvalue = db.Query("SELECT * FROM document_data WHERE doc_id = @0", doc_id);
}

<input type="text" class=" form-textbox" id="input_4" name="q4_arborLoan" size="20" value="@Helpers.checkEmpty(queryinputvalue,"q4_arborLoan")" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you doing this in `View`? You have to check for these conditions in the controller while populating your `ViewModel`as below:

```
public class ViewModel
{
  public string QueryValue {get ; set;}
}
```

And in your controller method you would simply populate this model and return it in View page.

```
public ActionResult MyMethod()
{
    ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
    //Get someValue from anywhere.
    string reqValue = someValue.FirstOrDefault(r => r.field_name.Equals("q15_2013Collections[0][]"));
    string queryValue = string.Empty();
    if(queryValues != null)
    {
       queryValue = string.IsNullOrEmpty(reqValue .field_data)
                  ? ""
                  : reqValue .field_data;
    }
    model.QueryValue = queryValue ;               
    return View(model);
}
```

So, your View will simply become

```
@model ViewModel

<input id="lead-entry" class="form-textbox" type="text" size="5" name="q15_2013Collections[0][]" value="@Model.QueryValue" />
```

Comment: I'm not using MVC. But the above code helped a lot. I created a @helper which is based on your code and is working well. The revised code is below.